# Traefik V2.0 Metrics with Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, metrics, traefik

If I want to capture metrics of Traefik with Prometheus, this only works if insecure= true is activated. If I set insecure=false I get a 404. Maybe someone has an example of what a correct configuration looks like. So the configuration of Traefik (V2.0 CLI) and the prometheus.yml.

traefik.yml command Section:

```
      command:
        - "--metrics=true"
        - "--metrics.prometheus=true"
        - "--metrics.prometheus.buckets=0.100000, 0.300000, 1.200000, 5.000000"
        - "--metrics.prometheus.entrypoint='metrics'"
        - "--metrics.prometheus.addEntryPointsLabels=true"
        - "--metrics.prometheus.addServicesLabels=true"

        - "--api=true"
        - "--api.dashboard=true"

        - "--log.level=INFO"

        - "--providers.docker=true"
        - "--providers.docker.swarmmode=true"
        - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"

        - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
        - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
        - "--certificatesResolvers.sec.acme.email=foo@bar.com"
        - "--certificatesResolvers.sec.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
        - "--certificatesResolvers.sec.acme.httpChallenge.entryPoint=web"
      deploy:
        labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"

            - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=PathPrefix(`/api`) || PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.api.rule=Host(`foo.bar`)"

            - "traefik.http.routers.api.service=api@internal"
            - "traefik.http.routers.api.middlewares=myauth"
            - "traefik.http.services.api.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
            - "traefik.http.routers.api.tls.certresolver=sec"
            - "traefik.http.middlewares.myauth.basicauth.users=xxx"
```

prometheus.yml:

```
global:
    scrape_interval: 10s
    scrape_timeout: 10s
scrape_configs:
    - job_name: 'pushgateway'
      static_configs:
              - targets: ['pushgateway:9091']
      honor_labels: true
    - job_name: 'traefik'
      scheme: https
      static_configs:
              - targets: ['foo.bar']
      basic_auth:
              username: myusername
              password: mypassword
```

Comment: From what I understand, the endpoint is /metrics, which is missing in your router PathPrefixes. That fact that it works with "insecure" is probably because with insecure, all api endpoints are available at :8080 regardless of router configuration.

Comment: Hi same issue here, I even don't get metrics with insecure flag.....
Have you find any workaround ? There is no explicit example with Traefik 2.0.

Comment: Metrics are a separate endpoint and need a separate endpoint definition per @timmr's answer.  The metrics do not have an accompanying router/service in the dashboard...it is just Traefik daemon opening another port.  Docker exec'ing into the Traefik container and then adding curl (`apk add curl`) and then hitting endpoint should work (`curl -k localhost:8082/metrics`) as a minimum test.  Incidentally you should be able to see Traefik listening ports by (`apk add nmap; nmap localhost`) and this should show 8082 open when the entrypoint is defined.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First expose 8082 port if you're in docker.

And add these commands when starting Traefik.

```
--metrics.prometheus=true
--metrics.prometheus.entryPoint=metrics
--entryPoints.metrics.address=:8082
```

Access that metrics in `domain:8082/metrics`

If you also add the following labels it will allow you to access the metrics on `traefikmetrics.mydomain.com/metrics`. You need to fill in the values in the angle braces depending on your setup.

```
traefik.http.routers.traefikmetrics.entrypoints: <http or https entrypoint>
traefik.http.routers.traefikmetrics.rule: Host(`traefikmetrics.mydomain.com`)
traefik.http.services.<traefik-service-name>.loadbalancer.server.port: 8082
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a working configuration for a prometheus metrics endpoint behind the Traefik reverse proxy itself without using the insecure configuration (although using a toml configuration file) - not quite sure, if that is what you want to achieve.

So from your example configuration above, from what I understand, you are missing some stuff.

First you configured the prometheus metrics to use the entrypoint 'metrics', so you need to configure an entrypoint called metrics in the CLI section, e.g. like this:

```
 - "--entrypoints.metrics.address=:8082"
```

If you want to access the metrics endpoint via TLS (terminated by traefik itself) and use basic authentication, you need a router configuration and service for the metrics endpoint as labels, e.g. like the following (additionally to your configuration of the api endpoint):

```
   - "traefik.http.routers.metrics.rule=PathPrefix(`/metrics`)"
   - "traefik.http.routers.metrics.rule=Host(`foo.bar`)"
   - "traefik.http.routers.metrics.tls=true"
   - "traefik.http.routers.metrics.tls.certResolver=sec"
   - "traefik.http.routers.metrics.service=metrics"
   - "traefik.http.routers.metrics.middlewares=myauth"
   - "traefik.http.services.metrics.loadbalancer.server.port=8082"
```

Additionally I needed to configure the docker swarm network like this (otherwise I am getting a 503 Gateway timeout):

```
- "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
```

(proxy is my overlay network connecting traefik and all services which Traefik will be the reverse proxy for.)

Hope that helps...

Comment: Welcome @timmr.  The point you make about defining the entrypoint is spot on.  However, I've got a working config without any of the router/services definitions that you suggest above.  My understanding (and experience) is that simply by adding entrypoint section and accompanying metrics section in toml is sufficient to have the Traefik engine expose metrics correctly.  Now, if you are separately running prometheus as a docker service (we are) then you will need Traefik labels there to expose prometheus, and need to configure prometheus to add Traefik as a target.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @fifofonix. I guess with your suggestions, you then need to expose the metrics-port to the host (like -ports "8082:8082")? My understanding was, that the OP wanted to access the metrics endpoint via TLS (terminated by Traefik) and secured by basic auth?

Comment: Got it. I think you may be right re OP’s question. Yes with my suggestion you’d have to expose the port to the swarm overlay network which may or may not be desirable depending on architecture.  You got me thinking and I made a local install with a router, as you've shown here successfully validating you can actually hit it via the main 443 entrypoint, but hitting the metrics service on the internally available 8082, as long as you use a PathPrefix for metrics.  Hadn't thought of that so thanks!  And, I verified it works regardless of API insecure option.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the api **and** dashboard in secure mode then you will need to use the api@internal 'magic' explained in the Traefik documentation [here](https://docs.traefik.io/operations/api/).

This means adding a label like:

```
"traefik.http.routers.<my-api-dash-name>.service=api@internal"
```

Needless to say this is not cool.  In essence we are treating this as a special snowflake situation, as opposed to using standard Traefik service declarations.  It appears that this is somewhat acknowledged, and future Traefik versions plan at a minimum to make this internal service appear in the dashboard.

Note that when you use insecure mode for the dashboard it opens up port 8080 on your local Traefik server.  When you switch to secure 8080 is closed.

I, like you, sought to declare my dashboard/api securely by routing internally to 8080.  If you are doing so via https and some auth mechanism, and not even exposing 8080 as a docker service port then arguably IMO you could be considered secure - but you will need to leave the insecure dashboard switch in your Traefik config so that you can leverage 8080 in this way.

If others have views on the security model described in prior paragraph vs. the cryptic api@internal I am all ears.

Comment: This is what I do. And in secure mode I can't access the metrics.

Comment: Can you try taking out the 8080 declaration you have?  In secure mode that port is closed and unreachable.